# LINQ - Get items of list1 that are present in list2 to list3

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<int>` say `list1` and `list2`.
Now I need to create a LINQ expression which should work in a way that for each item in list1, if it is available in list2 then store it in list3. For example, list1 contains `{5, 10, 15}` and list2 contains `{3, 5, 15, 20}`. Then with the help of LINQ, `list3`should contain {5,15}. What I tried is -

```
list3 = list1.Where(t1 => list2.Any(t2 => t1.Contains(t2))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Fine, what went wrong in your case?

Comment: @un-lucky - 'int' does not contain definition for 'Contains'.

Comment: `t1` is the int, not the list. Your problem is that you need to use `list1.Contains` instead of `t1.Contains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As like other answers stated, `Intersect` will be a fine option for you, But i would like to fix the error in your code, Actually you should performs `.Contains` operation in `List2` not in elements of `List2`. One more thing you have to note is that, the LHS of the assignment operation is of type `List<int>` so you have to use `.ToList()` instead for `.ToArray()`.  which means you have to wrote like this:

```
list3 = list1.Where(t1 => list2.Contains(t1)).ToList();
```

Or something like This:

```
list3 = list1.Where(t1 => list2.Any(x=> x == t1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list3 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list3 = (from p in list1 where list2.Contains(p) select p).ToList();
```